# Why is DynamoDB adding a NULL suffix to attribute names?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-go

I've been working on a toy project and noticed that dynamo added a (NULL) suffix in two of my attribute names. I had not noticed before, so I assume it must have happened after one of my code changes. I could not find any reference to this behavior online.

[image: dynamodb null attribute name suffix]

The script I'm running is a simple `PutItem` got from the official Dynamodb documentation, where I insert a few mock users in a table.

```golang
func InsertModel(m interface{}) error {
    av, err := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(m)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("handlers: Got error marshalling map: %v", err)
    }

    input := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
        Item:                av,
        TableName:           aws.String(appTableName),
        ConditionExpression: aws.String("attribute_not_exists(PK) AND attribute_not_exists(SK)"),
    }

    _, err = svc.PutItem(input)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("handlers: Got error calling PutItem: %v", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

`m` (user mock data) has all fields type `string`:

```golang
UserModel{PK: "910cc6d8-b7e2-dfg6-d8d4-sh6d0e3fde6b", SK: "user_info", Name: "bla", ImageURI: "aaa"},
```

When I remove the fields "Name" and "ImageURI", the `PutItem` inserts a boolean `true` to the field value as seen below.

[image: dynamodb boolean attr value when not present in putitem]

Here is the value in `av` after the MarshalMap operation.

1. with populated "Name" and "ImageURI" fields:

```golang
map[ImageURI:{
  S: "aaa"
} Name:{
  S: "bla"
} PK:{
  S: "910cc6d8-b7e2-dfg6-d8d4-sh6d0e3fde6b"
} SK:{
  S: "user_info"
}]
```

2. and here without "Name" and "ImageURI" as in `UserModel{PK: "910cc6d8-b7e2-dfg6-d8d4-sh6d0e3fde6b", SK: "user_info"}`

```golang
map[ImageURI:{
  NULL: true
} Name:{
  NULL: true
} PK:{
  S: "910cc6d8-b7e2-dfg6-d8d4-sh6d0e3fde6b"
} SK:{
  S: "user_info"
}]
```

I have tried to delete all the records from the table and insert again but the behavior continues. Also, I did the same process for an `int` type attribute (inserting the object with the int attribute populated and not populated) and I get 0 when it's not populated (which is what I'd expect). I tried replicating this with a different string type attribute, and I get the same behavior (true when empty), but the attribute name doesn't get the suffix NULL.

So in summary, it seems this behavior is mostly happening with type `string` in my case, and I only get a NULL suffix in the attributes "Name" and "ImageURI", but not on the other string attribute I've tried (nor the int one).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for one of the fields of my table items.
For that field I was doing an update using the NameMap option, useful when you want to use a name that, for some other reasons, is reserved by dynamo. 
I just tried not to use the NameMap option, giving another name for my field, and that suffix disappeared. 
I hope my experience could be somehow helpful.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

**Option A**

The `dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap` method reads json struct tags if present. By adding `omitempty` it will leave the attribute off of the item. Then when reading it back later, it will default to the empty value in the struct.

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar string `json:"bar,omitempty"`
}
```

**Option B**

You can explicitly set empty struct values by either creating your own `dynamodb.AttributeValue` or implement the marshaller interface on your struct. For example:

```
item := map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
  "Foo": {
    S: aws.String("")
  }
}
```

**Making the (NULL) suffix to go away**

After deleting all the rows containing a NULL value in a column with the `(NULL)` suffix, it seems to take some time for the suffix to go away from the AWS UI. When I tested this, it took roughly 12 hours.

**Discussion**

Continue the discussion of null behaviors on github.

- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/pull/2419
- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues?q=MarshalMap+null